# Como iniciar editando um JFrame na mão e continuar os ajustes finais pelo "painel" do Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Consegui criar escrevendo o código ou gerando um novo arquivo do tipo javaswing + `JFrame`, mas gostaria de fazer escrevendo o código e continuar a edição com o "painel", sem precisar adicionar um "novo arquivo.

Comment: Voce que saber comom criar um jframe sem usar o editor do netbeans]?

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. Não entendi o que você está tentando fazer. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: O colega Articuno explicou bem o que eu queria perguntar: "Pelo que entendi, você pretende criar o JFrame do zero na mão e continuar editando usando a ferramenta gui-builder do netbeans,(...)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você pretende criar o `JFrame` do zero na mão e continuar editando usando a ferramenta *gui-builder* do netbeans, e isso pode não ser tão simples, pois o netbeans cria um arquivo `.form`, com dados em xml, onde ele armazena toda a configuração necessária para ele renderizar a tela. Criando na mão, a ferramenta não saberá como renderizar, portanto, ele não vai abrir uma classe criada por você.

Sem contar que o criador de telas tem uma característica na hora de criar telas, que é o fato dele utilizar um dos gerenciadores de layout mais complicados de dar manutenção, que é o [GroupLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html), e talvez você queira optar por mesclar gerenciadores ou utilizar outros que otimizem a codificação, e a ferramenta não ira saber como lidar com eles.

A ferramenta de criação de tela é um facilitador pra quem nao quer perder tempo criando designer em "linha de comando", isso é bastante desgastante quando se tem prazos e uma regra de negocio complicada de se desenvolver, então você precisa decidir se quer cortar essa etapa e utilizar a ferramenta ou se quer aventurar e fazer manualmente.

Já no caso do [*window builder*](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), que é a ferramenta semelhante mas compatível com eclipse, ele já consegue identificar telas criadas a mão. Um contra dessa ferramenta é que ela não é tão automatizada quanto a do netbeans, ela deixa tudo mais ao controle do programador.

Ainda sim, talvez seja uma boa alternativa, pois essa ferramenta do netbeans vai te prender a ele quando precisar dar manutenção de tela, pois com o tanto de código que ele cria, fica quase impossível dar manutenção numa interface mais complexa, e o *window builder* te dá mais liberdade entre programar utilizando o *drag 'n drop* da ferramenta e mexer manualmente no código do design da tela, além de possibilitar ver a renderização da interface em tempo real, sem "sujar" demais o código e sem criar arquivos extras.

Comment: Exatamente, pensei isso --> "Pelo que entendi, você pretende criar o JFrame do zero na mão e continuar editando usando a ferramenta gui-builder do netbeans,"

Comment: @LUIZ menos mal, então a resposta foi certa :D

Comment: No futuro pesquisarei mais sobre windows builder. Obrigado pela ajuda!